# startActivity and startSubActivity

Tags: android, start-activity, startactivityforresult

Can anyone tell me the difference between `startActivity` and `startActivityForResult`?

Is `startActivity` used to call `Activity` asynchronously and `startActivityForResult` for a synchronous call?

Are `startActivity(intent)` and `startActivityForResult(intent,-1)` same?

Comment: Is this question from oDesk "Google Android programming test"? :) :)

Comment: :) yeah , but m still seeking for a right answer ;)

Answer (score 11):

Both `startActvity()` and `startActivityForResult()` are ASYNCHRONOUS.

Comment: Is it not startActivityForResult synchronous ?.

Answer (score 10):

There is no `startSubActivity()` in Android. It was replaced a long time ago by `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no `startSubActivity()` in Android. It was replaced a long time ago by `startActivityForResult()`.
2. The difference between them is that:
   `startActivityForResult()` starts an activity and expects something in return;
   `startActivity()` just starts an activity without worrying about getting any result.
3. No. Both `startActvity()` and `startActivityForResult()` are ASYNCHRONOUS.
4. Yes. `startActivity(intent)` and `startActivityForResult(intent,-1)` do the same.